# FileNotFound after successful file creation

Tags: android, exception

I've downloaded a csv file info files by:

```
         File file = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/data2.csv");
//         File file = new File("data2.csv");
         try {
            ftp.connect("x.x.x.x");
            ftp.login("xx", "xx");
            ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/");
            ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            OutputStream outputStream = null;
            boolean success = false;
            try {
                outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                success = ftp.retrieveFile("data.csv", outputStream);
            } finally {
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
```

After that I cheked my applications ddms, and the file data2.csv was there.

Then I just  wanted to open it by

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"data2.csv")));
```

and after several attempts, it throws "filenotfoundexception". What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
 CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"data2.csv")));
```

change it to:

```
 CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"data2.csv")));
```

Comment: The constructor InputstreamReader(String) is undefined.

Comment: Yeah.. use this
new FileInputStream(new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"data2.csv"));

Comment: Hi, from ddms saw that the files that are being saved in file path from FTP download has only -rw------- permission. Do you think that can prevent me from reading ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `new FileInputStream(...)` instead of `getAssets().open(...)`.